# Duplicate rows in a table based on foregin key in the same table - oracle sql / plsql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have this table contain primary key , and foreign key as reference to it
as show

Table name = ACV_FOLDERS_INFO

Columns =
ID   ----------------------------PK

OWNER
NAME
ALT_NAME
CATEGORY
DESCRIPTION
ICON
DELETED
FDR_PUBLIC
INHERIT_PARENT_ACL
REMARKS
FIO_ID   ------------------------FK Reference to the PK (when FIO_ID is null thats mean the record is the  main folder)

OTHER_ID
YEAR
REF

The table build like this to create a TREE

I am trying to duplicate a the entire row (folder) and their sub folder based on FIO_ID referenced by ID and I still have a problem

[image: Data]

/*** lasted code .

```sql
declare
  l_ID number;
begin
  for i in (select case
                     when connect_by_isleaf = 1 then
                      0
                     when level = 1 then
                      1
                     else
                      -1
                   end as status,
                   level,
                   
                   f.*
            
              from acv_folders_info f,
                   (SELECT *
                      FROM acv_folder_acl
                     WHERE privilege = 'B'
                       and ERD_ID = 483) a
             where F.ID = A.FIO_ID
               and acv_get_validation.have_upd(p_erd_id => 483,
                                               p_fio_id => a.FIO_ID) = 'Y'
               and A.ERD_ID = 483
               and year = 2020
             start with F."FIO_ID" is null
            connect by prior f."ID" = F."FIO_ID"
             order by status desc, level) loop
    begin
      insert into acv_folder_info x
        (x.ID,
         x.OWNER,
         x.NAME,
         x.ALT_NAME,
         x.CATEGORY,
         x.DESCRIPTION,
         x.ICON,
         x.DELETED,
         x.FDR_PUBLIC,
         x.INHERIT_PARENT_ACL,
         x.REMARKS,
         x.FIO_ID,
         x.OTHER_ID,
         x.YEAR,)
      values
        (null,
         483,
         i.name || ' - 2020 / 2021',
         i.alt_name || ' - 2020 / 2021',
         i.category,
         i.description,
         i.icon,
         i.deleted,
         i.fdr_public,
         i.inherit_parent_acl,
         i.remarks,
         nvl(i.ID, l_ID),
         i.other_id,
         2020);
      returning id
        into l_ID;
    
    exception
      when others then
        dbms_output.put_line(i.id || ' - ' || l_ID || sqlerrm);
    end loop;
  end;
```

Comment: "I still have a problem" However, you have not told us what the problem is.

Comment: You appear to be missing an `END;` (before the `END LOOP;`) to terminate the PL/SQL block inside the loop. And an extra comma in the column list of the `INSERT`.

Comment: I cant get the new ID to put it as reference to FK foreign key  you can check the image to see the data arrange

Comment: You always insert `null` into the `id` column and then return that `null` value into the `l_id` pl/sql variable. It is unclear how you expect that value to be anything other than `null`.

Comment: Man come on , (ID is null but it work on trigger BIS/BIR if is it null it will call a sequence.nextval)   - the loop is sorts based on the main folder to the sub to the sub to the sub i get the main folder id and inserted into the foreign for the next level and took the next level id and inserted to the fio_id

Comment: How are we supposed to know there is a trigger if you **NEVER** mention it?

Comment: i am pretty sure that every oracle developer know about the trigger especially its the best case scenario and its almost a postulates

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided a minimal example of your tables or any sample data that can be copy/pasted and you have defined functions and triggers that you have never shared the source code for so it is impossible to test your code.

However, you want to use `ORDER SIBLINGS BY ...` in the cursor so that it is evaluated in a depth-first search order and you can store the generated ids in an associative array.

Something like (untested because your question is missing so many dependencies):

```sql
declare
  l_ID acv_folder_info.id%TYPE;
  TYPE ids_assoc_array IS TABLE OF NUMBER INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
  l_ids ids_assoc_array;
begin
  for i in (
    select f.*
    from   acv_folders_info f
           INNER JOIN acv_folder_acl a
           ON F.ID = A.FIO_ID
    WHERE  privilege = 'B'
    and    ERD_ID = 483
    and    acv_get_validation.have_upd(
             p_erd_id => 483,
             p_fio_id => a.FIO_ID
           ) = 'Y'
    and    A.ERD_ID = 483
    and    year = 2020
    start with F."FIO_ID" is null
    connect by prior f."ID" = F."FIO_ID"
    order siblings by name
  )
  loop
    insert into acv_folder_info (
      ID,
      OWNER,
      NAME,
      ALT_NAME,
      CATEGORY,
      DESCRIPTION,
      ICON,
      DELETED,
      FDR_PUBLIC,
      INHERIT_PARENT_ACL,
      REMARKS,
      FIO_ID,
      OTHER_ID,
      YEAR
    ) values (
      null,
      483,
      i.name || ' - 2020 / 2021',
      i.alt_name || ' - 2020 / 2021',
      i.category,
      i.description,
      i.icon,
      i.deleted,
      i.fdr_public,
      i.inherit_parent_acl,
      i.remarks,
      l_ids(i.FIO_ID),
      i.other_id,
      2020
    ) RETURNING id INTO l_ID;

    l_ids(i.id) := l_id;
  end loop;
end;
/
```